# Uniqueness of the boundary of a hierarchically hyperbolic group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Hierarchically hyperbolic groups and spaces (HHG and HHS for short) were defined by Behrstock, Hagen and Sisto (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2171) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00632)). Examples include mapping class groups, Right angled Artin groups, other cubical groups.

HHG can be equipped with a boundary, defined [there](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01061). This boundary is endowed with a topology. However, a HHG can be endowed with different hierarchically hyperbolic structures. The question I ask is the following:

Does the boundary depends on the HH structure, that is, given two choices of HH structures, are the boundaries homeomorphic ?

In the [paper cited above where the boundary is defined](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01061), it is proved the following. CAT(0) cube complexes can be given a HH structure, using the so-called factor systems (see [the first paper cited above](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2171)). For different choices of factor systems, the boundary is the same (it is homeomorphic to the simplicial boundary, endowed with some topology). So, this is a partial answer to my question.

The reason I ask this is that I mainly speak relative hyperbolicity. Given a relatively hyperbolic group $\Gamma$, one can choose different relatively hyperbolic structures (this corresponds here to choosing different collections of peripheral subgroups). If the peripheral subgroups are amenable, then the Bowditch boundary does not depend on the relative hyperbolic structure, but in general it does.

Comment: One nice important fact about the boundary of a hyperbolic group/space is that its metric is unique up to quasi-symmetric equivalence (in particular, its Hausdorff dimension is well-defined). So I'd not interpret the uniqueness of the boundary up to homeomorphism as a definite uniqueness result.

Comment: Yes you're right, but before asking about uniqueness of the metric, I wanted to ask about uniqueness of the homeomorphism type, since I'm not even sure it holds.

Comment: I think (but may be confused and don't have time to check) that both the original question and @YCor's refinement are answered positively in this preprint of Mousley and Russell: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04867 .

Comment: @HJRW Oh okay, thanks. I've checked this paper, but not in details. I thought it only dealt with the Morse boundary, which indeed only depends on the group.

Comment: @M.Dus, no, sorry, I think you're right and I was mixed up.  Too many boundaries!  I thought that Hagen told me that the HHS boundary was known to be only an invariant of the space, but I may have misremembered.

Comment: I think it is open whether or not it depends on the HH structure.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to note that on page 4 of [the paper itself](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01061) you will find the following more structured version of your question: Given two HH structures on the same space $X$ (e.g. on the same group), does the identity map on $X$ extend continuously to a map from $X$ union one boundary to $X$ union the other, so that the map in turn restricts to a homeomorphism between the boundaries?

Comment: It is open whether it depends on the HH structure.  There are some cases where it's known to be independent of the HH structure (for example, if the space is hyperbolic, then the HH boundary wrt any HH structure is homeomorphic to the Gromov boundary).

(@HJRW, probably I told you about the cubical case, e.g. in a RAAG/RACG it shouldn't matter whether you've used the naive HH structure one can obtain by coning off all parabolic subgroups, or the "minimal" HH cubical HH structure arising from the hyperplanes.  But I don't remember either :-))

Comment: @MarkHagen Thank you! The case of RAAGS is already interesting. You say that for the different "usual" HH structures on those, the boundary are/should be the same ? BTW, is it expected to depend on the structure or not (or maybe we just don't know what to expect yet) ?

Comment: @M. Dus: For RAAGs, any two factor systems on the universal cover of the Salvetti complex give HH structures with the same boundary.  In principle, there could be an HH structure, not coming from a factor system, with a different boundary.

Comment: @M. Dus: Another test case might be: there's a useful construction due to Abbott, Behrstock, and Durham (<a href="https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06219">see Theorem 3.11</a>) that converts an HH structure on a space X to a different one with a nice property, under some natural conditions.  It might be interesting to see whether doing that construction can alter the boundary.  (I guess not.)

I don't have a good guess in general.  It would be very convenient to have a description of the topology on the boundary that's easier to work with that the existing definition!

Comment: @MarkHagen Thank you very much for the clarification! I guess there is a lot to do then :)